# Divergence of sequence with limit $\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I adapt the ratio test for a finite equation to answer a question that involves infinity?

Answer (score 2):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges as soon as $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L\in (1,+\infty]$.

In fact, by definition of limit, $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ implies that there is a $N$ such that for $n\geq N$, $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$.
Hence for $n\geq N$, $a_n\geq a_N>0$, and for  any $m\geq 0$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\geq \sum_{n=N}^{N+m} a_n\geq (m+1)a_N$$
By the arbitrarity of $m$, the series diverges.